# CSS highlight doesn't display

Tags: css

I am doing a basic highlight exercise, and i don't know why it is not working. In the list there is one item that has the class "selected", that is also the id of the body, and in the css such ids and classes are called for changing the background of the item.

html:

```
<body id="selected">



<ol class="pagination" >
    <li><a href="index.html" rel="prev">prev</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" rel="next">next</a></li>
</ol>


</body>
```

CSS

```
    * { 
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#selected .pagination .selected a {
    background-color: blue;
    cursor: default;
}

ol.pagination li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

ol.pagination a, ol.pagination li.selected  {
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ol.pagination a:hover, ol.pagination a:focus, ol.pagination a:active, ol.pagination li.selected {
    color:white;
    background-color:blue;
}

ol.pagination a[rel="prev"],
ol.pagination a[rel="next"] {
    border:none;
}

ol.pagination a[rel="prev"]:before {
    content: "\00AB";
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}

ol.pagination a[rel="next"]:after  {
    content: "\00BB";
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
```

And the "2" box is not highlighting, why?. as the body id is "selected" shouldn't it change?.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
#selected .pagination .selected a {
background-color: blue;
cursor: default;
}
```

To this

```
#selected .pagination .selected {
background-color: blue;
cursor: default;
}
```

This will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

With `.selected a` you are selecting *each `a` element which is a child of an element with a class `.selected`*.

Your selector should look more like this:

```
#selected .pagination a.selected
```

But maybe you don't need to be so specific. Maybe just doing:

```
a.selected
```

Would be ok for you.

Comment: If an answer was good for you, vote it up and/or accept it. You'll maybe visit http://stackoverflow.com/about to know how StackOverflow works. Welcome!